# Google Sheets Query Works with Contains but not with Matches

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language, multiple-matches

I can't figure out why my query with Matches does not work while it works fine with contains.  I want to eventually pipe additional things into the match but need it to work first.

Contains: `=QUERY(Raw!A2:P,"SELECT * WHERE K contains '<m>, 5/2/2020' ",0)`

Matches: `=QUERY(Raw!A2:P,"SELECT * WHERE K matches '.*<m>, 5/2/2020.*' ",0)`

it semi-works when I remove/change the 5 but doesn't return all the matches... the sample data provided won't allow testing but I tested with 2,3,4,6 for example:  `=QUERY(Raw!A2:P,"SELECT * WHERE K matches '.*<m>, 3.*' ",0)`

Sample data for one cell in column K:

```
Keith <k>, 5/2/2020: @Me: Thank you
_______________________
Keith <k>, 5/2/2020: @S: this is some text
_______________________
Mo <m>, 5/2/2020: @Me: more text is here
_______________________
ME <me>, 5/6/2020: text is here
_______________________
Jonathan <j>, 5/6/2020: @Me: Thank your
_______________________
Jonathan <j>, 5/6/2020: @S: text
```

Comment: Provide sample data as text

Comment: Provide "sample": dummy strings that prove that the issue actually exists. See [mcve]. If I were to copy your text to a sample column with your formula, I should be able to reproduce the problem, which you claim exists.

Comment: I'm stumped then... my sheet keeps sayin query completed with empty output.

Comment: Reproducible if put in "one cell"

Comment: is it possible the code is executing 5/2/2020 as a math equation? so it's looking for .0012376 instead of the actual text of 5/2/2020?

Comment: No. It's the absence of single line regex flag support`(?s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query's matches in Google sheets web app(unlike  official mobile apps) doesn't seem to support regex flags like single line mode: `(?s)`. Consider creating a issue with a link to this post in

- [Google Visualization issues](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues)
- Google sheets > Help > Help sheets improve.

---

#### Workarounds:

- Query function seems to run client side unlike other functions. If supported use, `(?s)` like:

  ```
  =QUERY(Raw!A2:P,"SELECT * WHERE K matches '(?s).*<m>, 5/2/2020.*' ",0)
  ```
- If not, simulate single line mode using `(.|\n)` (any character or new line):

  ```
  =QUERY(Raw!A2:P,"SELECT * WHERE K matches '(.|\n)*<m>, 5/2/2020(.|\n)*' ",0)
  ```
- Use `contains` instead. `contains` with `OR` should simulate `matches`' pipe `|` joining.

  ```
  =QUERY(Raw!A2:P,"SELECT * WHERE K contains "&JOIN( " or K contains ","'<m>, 5/2/2020'" ,"'<k>'")&"",0)
  ```

Comment: Yeah I'm just going to use contains.  The idea was to be able to enter a start and end date and have the query pull all entries from a user with those dates so if you specified say 5/2/2020 to 5/9/2020 for user <m> it would look for <m>, 5/2/2020 or <m>, 5/3/2020 or <m>, 5/4/2020 or ... <m>, 5/9/2020.  based on [research](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/multiple-contains-in-where-clause-in-query) i thought building a  textjoin to create a string to pipe them together would be best but guess not.